# Remove the redis of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, composer-php

I have a LARAVEL server that Redis has already installed on it

How do I remove Redis from the Laravel ? ( laravel v5.5 )

```
'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],
```

Comment: Remove the application Redis or the PHP client for Redis?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, but if I understand it well, 
You just need to remove the composer package you added for using redis, usually `PRedis`.

Simply remove the pacakge from composer.json and run `composer install` in the command line or `composer remove vendor/package`